OpenSSHのカスタムインストール後、sshサービスが再起動時に失敗します
Ubuntu上でOpenSSH（バージョン9.9p1）をカスタムインストールしていますが、再起動後にSSHサービスが起動に失敗する問題に直面しています。アドバイスや解決策をご教示いただけると幸いです．
以下にセットアップの手順，接続時のエラー文を記載しております．
以下の手順でセットアップを行いました：

旧バージョンのOpenSSHを削除：

sudo apt remove --purge openssh-server openssh-client


必要な依存関係をインストール

sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev


最新のOpenSSHソースコードをダウンロードしてコンパイル

wget ftp://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.9p1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssh-9.9p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-9.9p1
./configure
make
sudo make install


サービスを再起動：特権管理用ユーザーsshdが存在しないとのエラーが出現

sudo systemctl restart sshd


SSHサービスを構成：

・セキュリティ対策としてsshdユーザーを作成：
sudo useradd -r -d /var/empty -s /usr/sbin/nologin sshd

・設定ファイルを検証してサービスを起動
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sshd -t -f /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sshd


バージョン確認：この時点でバージョンが更新されていることを確認

ssh -V  # 出力: OpenSSH_9.9p1


永続化のために以下の内容でsystemdサービスファイルを作成

[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/sshd -D
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


systemdをリロードし、サービスを有効化

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ssh.service
sudo systemctl start ssh.service


サービスの状態確認

sudo systemctl status ssh.service

SSHサーバーがポート22を使用しようとしたものの、そのポートがすでに別のプロセスで使用されているため起動に失敗しているとのエラーが出現しました．
回避策のために別ポートを開けてsshを動作させました

別のポートでSSHを動作させる

10.1．コンフィグファイルのポート番号を2222に変更
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
10.2．コンフィグファイルの構文確認：異常なし
sudo /usr/local/sbin/sshd -t
10.3．ポートのファイアーウォールの許可
sudo ufw allow 2222/tcp

ssh再起動と状態確認→正常に実行されていることを確認

sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
sudo systemctl status ssh.service


ssh接続確認
外部のPCからSSH接続できるかを確認
→ポート22，2222両方においてssh接続できることを確認

サーバー再起動


sudo reboot

以下、再起動後の外部からのssh接続の確認を行った結果
「*********」はIPアドレス，PCのユーザー名，サーバーのホスト名が入ります

ポート22へのアクセスの結果

C:\Users\********>ssh -vvv ********
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for **********
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname *********** is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to *********** port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000002D0A0919D60
debug1: connect to address *********** port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ******** port 22: Connection refused


ポート2222へのアクセスの結果

C:\Users\********>ssh -vvv ********
OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5p1, LibreSSL 3.8.2
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/config line 9: Applying options for **********
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname *********** is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> 'C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> 'C:\\Users\\********/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to *********** port 2222.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:000002D0A0919D60
debug1: connect to address *********** port 2222: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ******** port 2222: Connection timed out

考えられる原因

サーバーが動作していない
ファイアーウォールでブロックされている

追記:
ローカルでログインし，以下の内容を確認しました．
$ sudo systemctl status sshd
Unit sshd.service could not found

$ sudo systemctl start sshd
Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found

$ which sshd
/usr/local/sbin/sshd

$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl

$ sudo systemctl status ssh
● ssh.service - OpenSSH server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2024-11-26 12:48:24 JST; 2h 55min ago
 Main PID: 1356 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 76656)
   Memory: 1.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─1356 sshd: /usr/local/sbin/sshd [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups

Nov 26 12:48:24 ＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊ systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server.
Nov 26 12:48:24 ＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊ sshd[1356]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
Nov 26 12:48:24 ＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊＊ sshd[1356]: Server listening on :: port 2222.

$ which sshd_config
表示なし

$ cd /etc/ssh
$ ls ssh
sshd_config~

$ cat sshd_config~
ポートの記載のみ確認
#Port 22

$ dpkg -1 | grep openssh-server
何も表示なし

$ sudo netstat -tuln | grep ssh
何も表示なし

sshd を動かしているサーバ自体からのSSH
$ ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22 :Connection refused

$ ssh localhost -p 2222
**********@localhost's password :
Last login : Fri 2024 Nov 29
ログインに成功しました


sshdを入れ替える前は外部から接続できていたのでしょうか？

コメントありがとうございます。
・手順１の前は，外部から接続出来ておりました．
・手順５の前は，外部からの接続確認は行っておりません．
理由としては，手順４のサービスの再起動に失敗し以下のエラー文が出力されたためです．
Privilege separation user sshd does not exist
make: [Makefile:396: check-config] Error 255 (ignored)
よろしくお願いいたします．

コンソールでログインして確認はしないのですか？それとも、SSHでしか接続できない環境なのですか？もしかして、作業はコンソールでは無く、全てSSHでログインして行ったのですか？

sshd が動いているサーバ自体で localhost に対しての接続はどうでしょうか？「外部からの接続」も曖昧なので (同一 LAN 内の別マシン or インターネット越しのアクセス etc)、もう少し環境についての詳しい情報があった方がよさそうなのと、どこが問題なのかを切り分けることをまず目指してみてください。 (元のパッケージを削除したならポート 22 が使われてるでエラーになるのも不可解です)

raccy様コメントありがとうございます。
・アップデート作業は全てSSHでログインして行いました．
・アップデート作業後，SSHでのログインは出来ませんでしたが，コンソールでのログインは確認致しました。

cubick様コメントありがとうございます。
「外部からの接続」とは，インターネット越しの別マシンからのSSH接続のことを指しております．

サービス起動用のユニットファイル sshd.service が正しく認識されていないようなので、OS 起動後に sshd が実行されないのもこれが原因でしょう。どこに保存したのか等も詳しく書いてみてください。

追記のsystemctlで指定するのは「sshd」ではなく「ssh」ではないですか。再起動前にはそのように指定していたようですが。

cubick様ありがとうございます。
openssh-serverのインストール確認を行ったところ，インストールされていないとの結果となりました．
systemctl status sshではsshはactiveとなっておりましたが，これはopenssh-serverが異なる名前でインストールされているという事でしょうか？とりあえず改めてインストールした方がいいのでしょうか？

katsuko様コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘の通りsshで指定しsystemctl start し，systemctl statusでactiveとなっていることを確認致しましたが，22，2222ポート共にssh接続できていない状態となっております．

sshd を動かしているサーバ自体で ssh localhost または ssh localhost -p 2222 での接続はできますか？

cubick様ありがとうございます。質問文に結果を追記いたしました．ポートを指定しない場合，自動的にポート22へsshアクセスし，アクセス拒否されました．ポート2222を指定した場合，ssh接続に成功しました．

以下の手順でSSH接続が復旧しました．
【手順】
sshを停止させる
sudo systemctl stop ssh
コンフィグファイルを編集しポートを22に変更
sudo nano /usr/local/etc/sshd_config
sshの再起動
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable ssh 
sudo systemctl start ssh

外部のデバイスからのSSH接続が出来ることを確認した，
【原因】
・SSH接続用のポートが誤って2222に設定されていたこと。
・sshd_configを修正する際、バックアップファイル(/etc/ssh/sshd_config~)を編集してしまい、SSHサービスが参照するべきファイル(/usr/local/etc/sshd_config)を正しく編集できていなかったこと。
最後になりますが，皆様からの多大なアドバイスに感謝申し上げます。

まずは [ss -ant] で待ち受けポートが外部からの接続を受け付けているか確認し、受け付けているなら「localhost」で接続できているのでファイアウォールになるのかな？
後、cubickさんが言われているポート 22 が何に使われているか [sudo lsof -i:22] で調べてみると何かヒントになるかもしれませんね。

hiend6409様コメントありがとうございます。
sudo lsof -i:22したところ，何も表示されず，一方でポート2222ではsshが使用しているとの結果となりました
